Is it possible to add a totally custom light type as an add-on?
I would like to create a custom light type in Blender that has an arbitrary behavior, such as a collimated light source (laser) or a light source with two different divergence angles along the two axes. I am not sure if this is possible with a simple add-on, or if I need to use a more complex approach.
My goal is to achieve a specific lighting effect that is not possible with the existing light types in Blender.
I would appreciate any advice on how to approach this task, including how the solution should differ for Cycles and Eevee.

Hello, have you explored custom IES files ?

Hi, yes. IES files are very useful, but they can't mimic very well some special sources, as for example laser lines or laser grids. Moreover, they have an intrinsic interpolation algorithm that reduces the sharpness of the beam.

I don't know about custom lights using only python. But as far as laser-like lights, I believe you can already make them on Cycles using area lights with their spread at zero to remove the "blurriness":

For a simple dot, you can just set the area light to be a sphere shape and use a small size.
For more complex shapes, use an image texture in the light's shader nodes to give the precise shape you want, such as a grid.


The method you suggest is definitely the best approach to get closer to the desired results. However, it still does not allow full customisation. For example, ‘spread = 0’ does not allow a source with two different divergences along the two transverse planes x and y.
The projected grid solution is great for Cycles, while it is not implemented within Eevee (at least in Blender 4.0 that I use; I don't know if Eevee Next will change anything in this regard).

@igmar I think, with enough skill and math, even such complex things should be possible in Blender's light nodes. I tried looking for a tutorial I watched quite a while ago now, but couldn't find it.

@lajawi Yes, it is a pity that there are not many tutorials on this subject! But, again, there seems to be no way to create a fully customised light type as an add-on, e.g. for use in Eevee, where no nodes are available....
